# Tree structure in BackboneJS: How to render them with Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, nested, backbone-views

I have a simple Backbone app that handles hierarchical items. The model (so far) is simple, it's supposed to contain only three attributes besides the `ID`: `content`, `order`, and `parent_id`. This last one attribute should contain the reference to it's parent model instance, or `null` if it's a root level item. The `order` attribute would be used to sort the items at the same level of the tree, and I want to implement some drag&drop functionality to manually sort the items.

The server side JSON already have the items sorted in tree order, but I'm not sure how to handle this in the views. Currently, what I'm doing in the item's view is adding a left padding to the `$el`ement to indicate some "indentation", but essentially it's still a flat list of items. That's why I'm not sure on how to implement the drag&drop sorting, preventing items to be dropped out of range (like above it's parent item)

How can I cleanly solve this model rendering using BackboneJS?

Comment: I once had implemented this exactly. The way i approached it was different. I did not hold references to parent element but used the parent element id inside a functions in my collection to produce child tree nodes, this had to be done under recursion to load N-level items. Finally every single parent was wrapped inside `<ul>` tag and children in `<li>` tag, for every parent also had `+`, `-` signs to collapse expand subtree. Always look at solutions that are easy and digestible

Comment: A single item view is more complicated than just `<li>`s, every of this views have actions and states of their own, and I want to prevent  CSS selectors that match on elements on a view also match elements in the views of it's child views.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't "pure" Backbone (it uses Marionette.js), but this post should be of interest for anyone looking into a similar issue: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/